# activating python venv from bash in Windows. How to resolve problem with line endings?

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, virtualenv

I have a bash script to deploy some code to AWS.  It mostly works but I'm having issues activating my virtual environment.   It seems it might be to do with line endings because I'm trying to activate a windows venv using Scripts/activate.

I see these types of errors in the logs:

Scripts/activate: line 3: $'\r': command not found
Scripts/activate: line 4: $'\r': command not found
Scripts/activate: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''

My script creates, installs packages then destroys the venv.  If I comment out the creating and destroy and change the line endings of the activate script to 'LF' it works.   So How can I force LF endings instead of CRLF on virtual env creation?

This is the line that is creating the env at the moment:
virtualenv $VENV

Answer (score 1):

fixed with dos2unix command

dos2unix Scripts/activate